# FireFox 66 Quantum disabled all my extensions at midnight!

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

This morning I woke up to:

[image: Extensions disabled]

and the FireFox help page doesn't really help...

*Help!  What should I do now???

**I need NoScript and AdBlock Plus to improve my surfing speed!!!*** 0:-)

Comment: this error is fixed now.addons are now avaliable and functioning.

Comment: @trondhansen for some people it only cropped up recently while for others it's been resolved.

Comment: a fix is released and will be rolled out over the next few hours,for firefox on android an update is needed but it is on its way right now.

Comment: **This was bug-related** and should be closed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Firefox 66.0.5 has now been released by Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/66.0.5/releasenotes/)** which avoids the Master Password issue in 66.0.4 which prevented the previous fix from working in some cases.

After the update arrives in the Ubuntu repositories, anyone who [has used the workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140474/344926) and disabled extension signing in `about:config` should re-enable it by double-clicking on the:

- `xpinstall.signatures.required` and
- `extenstions.langpacks.signatures.required`

settings again to set them back to the default value of `true`.

More Mozilla support information [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-ons-disabled-or-fail-to-install-firefox).

---

Obsolete now:

[Firefox 66.0.4 has been released by Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/66.0.4/releasenotes/) which should fix this without requiring the Studies functionality and **[is now in the package repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox)** for all supported branches of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fabby: 66.0.4 is now in the package repositories for all supported branches of Ubuntu. 66.0.5 will presumably also appear soon as it is already showing in Eoan (but 66.0.4 should fix the issue for the majority of users).

Comment: `apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
firefox/xenial-updates,xenial-security 66.0.4+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 66.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]` Changing acceptance.

Answer (score 18):

### This workaround is now obsolete.

[Please use the the official method to get rid of this issue...](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141338/344926)

Just open a new tab and go to `about:config` and filter on `signatures.required` and double click both of them to turn them from `true` to `false`:

[image: Nasty Red]

and the nasty red turns into a fine yellow:

[image: Nice Yellow]

*Which allows me to move on for the moment, until:*

- [the bug is corrected.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973)
  and
- [posted to the Ubuntu Repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141338/344926)

Comment: It would be even better if you add the link to the bugreport - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973 and Mozilla's twitter https://twitter.com/firefox/status/1124527050490933248 . To show that Mozilla knows about the problem and working hard with fixing it.

Comment: I do not know if it will work for long. Firefox is disabling extensions it does not approve and/or that have obfuscated code.

Comment: @DKBose I agree, that is why I said "it will not work for long"...but alas, it might not work for long, if we are pedantic today.

Comment: A [partial fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973#c57) is being pushed out via the [Normandy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Normandy/PreferenceRollout) route.

Comment: Note that to receive the fix via *Normandy* you must enable *Firefox studies* under *Privacy & Security*.

Comment: https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/03/a-glitch-is-breaking-all-firefox-extensions/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer_us=aHR0cHM6Ly9zbGFzaGRvdC5vcmcv&guce_referrer_cs=OEOXoqKtTSDw9_wfojbvhg

Comment: Will there be a regular fix as well, one in the form of an Ubuntu package update? When?

Comment: Any update on when this will be fixed in Ubuntu?

Comment: **IMHO:** Disabling security is neither *recommended*, nor a viable *long term solution*. Allowing 'Studies' (discussed below) also require diagnostics (data sent to Mozilla) to be enabled (although this is already **enabled** by default). Use this 'solution' until **66.0.4** (with actual fix, and replacement Add-Ons certificate) is released (via normal update process) to Ubuntu.

Comment: @david6 See comment below other answer: once released to the Ubuntu repositories, I'll be changing the acceptance of the answer.  **0:-)**  *For the moment,* this is the best solution yet...  **;-)**