# Problems with installing extensions ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, firefox-extensions

That happens with every extension that i try to install.

Any idea what is going wrong ?

[image: Trying to add extension:]

Comment: This looks like the recent bug with Firefox that automatically breaks addons, not an issue with the GNOME extensions website. Possible duplicate of [FireFox 66 Quantum disabled all my extensions at midnight!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140473/firefox-66-quantum-disabled-all-my-extensions-at-midnight)

Comment: Fixed it, your post helped ! Thanks